# TensorFlow Lite makefile for Texas Instruments CC1352P7 Board with ARM Cortex M4F multiprotocol

Tags: c++, arm, tensorflow-lite, cortex-m, tinyml

I am trying to use tensorflow lite to deploy a model on MCU Texas Instruments CC1352P7 having
ARM Cortex M4F protocol.

However, when trying to generate the makefile in my command line, I get the following error:

tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers already exists, skipping the download.
tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/kissfft already exists, skipping the download.
tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/pigweed already exists, skipping the download..
make: *** No rule to make target 'generate_projects'.  Stop.

Please do note - I have NO EXPERIENCE in C++ and/or hardware. Only in ML/AI model building using Python. So please be gentle. :)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks